# POSIX Bonjour/mDNSResponder test examples report "bind: Address already in use" on Ubuntu, but not Debian

Tags: c, sockets, posix, bonjour, mdns

When building the Apple's implementation of mDNS, aka. Bonjour, aka. mDNSResponder for a posix system  (http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/mDNSResponder/) [*]

- On a clean `Ubuntu 14.04` build box (with only `build-essentials, g++`), the compiled examples **fail to work**, and report `"bind: Address already in use"`.
- On a clean `Debian 7` build box (with only `build-essentials, g++`), the compiled examples **work**, and *do not* report `"bind: Address already in use"`.

What is going on here?

[*] which... is just riddled with bugs. For sanity, I suggest using versions 333.10, or 541, and applying patches from the umondo project: https://github.com/tklab-tud/umundo/tree/master/contrib/archives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the following difference in `/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h`

The `socket.h` in question is part of the `linux-libc-dev`  package.

In `Debian`, `socket.h` is from version `3.2.65` of `linux-libc-dev`, and contains contains the commented line

```
/* To add :#define SO_REUSEPORT 15 */
```

On `Ubuntu`, `linux-libc-dev` is version `3.13.0`. `socket.h`. Here, that line is no longer commented out:

```
#define SO_REUSEPORT    15
```

---

Of course, the problem is not with `linux-libc-dev`, but the use of this macro, in `mDNSPosix.c`, in particular, the lines:

```
#if defined(SO_REUSEPORT)
    err = setsockopt(*sktPtr, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &kOn, sizeof(kOn));
#elif defined(SO_REUSEADDR)
    err = setsockopt(*sktPtr, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &kOn, sizeof(kOn));
#else
    #error This platform has no way to avoid address busy errors on multicast.
#endif
```

By just swapping the order, to prioritize `SO_REUSEADDR`, there is no longer a socket binding issue. I.e.:

```
#if defined(SO_REUSEADDR)
    err = setsockopt(*sktPtr, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &kOn, sizeof(kOn));
#elif defined(SO_REUSEPORT)
    err = setsockopt(*sktPtr, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &kOn, sizeof(kOn));
#else
    #error This platform has no way to avoid address busy errors on multicast.
#endif
```

---

**Note:** This change has not been tested in `BSD`, which, if I understand correctly, should perhaps keep the priority in the order it was.

Comment: The reason I'm adding this here, is that this problem, and several other "this can't possible have passed compilation"-bugs (looking at you `mDNSShared/dnssd_clientshim.c`), has persisted in the bonjour library for many years. Making it doubtful that a bugreport will fix another such error in any timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the differences between SO_REUSEADDR AND SO_REUSEPORT.

SO_REUSEPORT was introduced in later Linux kernels and it appears the Ubuntu system image has support for it.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14388706/4463455) question for all you could ever want to know about REUSADDR/REUSEPORT.

The behavioral differences between REUSEADDR and REUSEPORT are that REUSEPORT places more restrictions on the sockets trying to reuse the same port: they all have to have the option set and exist within the same process. That's not the case with REUSEADDR.

Is it possible your Ubuntu image is also running another mDNS daemon like avahi?  You can run netstat to diagnose the other bound sockets in the system to identify the port collisions